# Add a custom attribute to socket.io and get this value in the server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to extend a property to my socket.io in the client side, with a custom value, like:

`var socket = io();
socket.customAttr = "123"`

and get this value in a node server, but I'm extending this functionallity in the client side, but in the server is always `undefinded`.

Exist a way to add customAttributes to the my socket.io?

Comment: The server side / client side socket are 2 completely different entities. There is no way to extend the socket library to be able to share values like that, if you could be more specific with what you're trying to accomplish by doing this it may be easier to get a more precise answer

Comment: You would need to send the value from the server to the client socket and on the client side store the value.

Comment: client and server are both different context. What you can do is send your custom attr to your server then let the server store that attr. probably in an object or array

Comment: Is it not possible to simply add an additional attribute to the socket object when opening a connection?

Comment: No, not is possible, as @Datsik says: The server side / client side socket are 2 completely different entities. There is no way to extend the socket library to be able to share values like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some one who finding a solution for this old question: Now (v4.x) you can use [`socket.handshake.query`](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#query).
Client:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client"; 
const socket = io({ query: { x: 42 } });
```

Server:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => { 
console.log(socket.handshake.query); // prints { x: "42"} 
});
```